# How to Stream a Map by value which is a Collection?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

How to stream a `Map<String, List<String>>` to get:

1. A `List<String>` of all the `String`s of the value `List`s of the `Map` which are longer than 5 characters? How to get long count of these?
2. A `Map<String, List<String>>` where keys stay the same, but the `List`s consist only of `String`s of length larger than 5?
3. A `Map<String, Long>` with counts of `String`s longer than 5 in `List` per map's key?

I started something but I am stuck:

```
long l = map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(m -> m.getValue().stream().filter(s -> s.length() > 5)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first question, you can merge the `List`s using `flatMap` and then filter out the short `String`s :

```
List<String> longStrings = 
    map.values()
       .stream()
       .flatMap(Collection::stream)
       .filter(s->s.length() > 5)
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For the second question, it looks like you want to create a new `Map` from the source `Map`, where the keys remain the same and the values are filtered :

Sample input :

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<> ();
map.put ("one", Arrays.asList (new String[]{"1","2","12345","123456"}));
map.put ("two", Arrays.asList (new String[]{"1","123456","12345","12"}));
map.put ("three", Arrays.asList (new String[]{"1","2","12","34"}));
map.put ("four", Arrays.asList (new String[]{"12345","123456","1234567","123"}));
```

Processing :

```
Map<String, List<String>> output =
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                 e->e.getValue()
                                     .stream()
                                     .filter(s -> s.length() > 5)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Output :

```
{four=[123456, 1234567], one=[123456], three=[], two=[123456]}
```

The third question is a minor variation of the second :

```
Map<String, Long> output =
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                 e->e.getValue()
                                     .stream()
                                     .filter(s -> s.length() > 5)
                                     .count()));
```

Comment: Thanks. Well, in first question i wanted to get back List<String> with all strings larger than 5, no matter what the key is. In second I wanted map as you did in your first example, and in third I wanted map but with counts instead of lists as value.  Thanks again

Comment: @Prpaa Edited to answer the first question.

Comment: If the source `Map` is mutable and the old state not required, the task `2` can be done as in-place operation: `map.values().forEach(list -> list.removeIf(s -> s.length() <= 5));`

Comment: Otherwise, Java 9 will have the necessary built-in collectors for this kind of task, i.e. `.collect( groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().stream(), filtering(s -> s.length() > 5, toList()))))` (getting a bit of LISP feeling) for task 2, which can be easily adapted to task 3 by replacing `toList()` with `counting()`…